# Parallel file processing using cloud services

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I have many images that I need to run through a java program to create more image files -- an embarrassingly parallel case. Each input file is about 500 mb, needs about 4 GB of memory during processing, and takes 30 seconds to 2 minutes to run. The java program is multithreaded but more gain comes from parallelizing on the input files than from using more threads. I need to kick off processes several times a day (I do not want to turn on/off the cluster manually nor pay for it 24/7).

I'm a bit lost in the variety of cloud options out there:

- Amazon [lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda) has insufficient system resources (not enough memory).
- Google Cloud [DataFlow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow), it appears that I would have to write my own pipeline source to use their Cloud Storage buckets. Fine, but I don't want to waste time doing that if it's not an appropriate solution (which it might be, I can't tell yet).
- Amazon [data pipeline](http://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) looks to be the equivalent to Google Cloud DataFlow. (*Added in edit for completeness.*)
- Google Cloud [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/), this is not a map/reduce hadoop-y situation, but might work nonetheless. I'd rather not manage my own cluster though.
- Google compute engine or AWS with autoscaling, and I just kick off processes for each core on the machine. More management from me but no APIs to learn.
- Microsoft [Data Lake](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/data-lake/) is not released yet and looks hadoop-y.
- Microsoft [Batch](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/batch/) seems quite appropriate (but I'm asking because I remain curious about other options).

Can anyone advise what appropriate solution(s) would be for this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to avoid Hadoop (or Spark) for this processing? I assume it's so you don't have to rewrite your app but I wanted to ask to be sure. :)

Comment: @James I'm not that familiar with Spark/Hadoop, so my reason might be flawed. The java program is a big third-party one that cannot practically be rewritten. (Although it can be wrapped in another java class via an API.) The practical method I saw was to invoke system processes, which then seemed to make Spark/Hadoop a poor fit. ...maybe?

Comment: Got it. Yeah, you could wrap it in another Java class and run it. It'd be fast and distributed but perhaps not elegant. For Cloud Dataproc, once you create a cluster, it's managed for you so the overall management level would be low. You could also adjust the cluster size dynamically based on need, which might be nice. If you are curious, LMK (but I do not want to hog this question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this with Dataflow quite easily. The pipeline could look something like (assuming your files are located on [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), GCS):

```
class ImageProcessor {
    public static void process(GcsPath path) {
        // Open the image, do the processing you want, write
        // the output to where you want.
        // You can use GcsUtil.open() and GcsUtil.create() for
        // reading and writing paths on GCS.
    }
}

// This will work fine until a few tens of thousands of files.
// If you have more, let me know.
List<GcsPath> filesToProcess = GcsUtil.expand(GcsPath.fromUri("..."));
p.apply(Create.of(filesToProcess))
 .apply(MapElements.via(ImageProcessor::process)
                   .withOutputType(new TypeDescriptor<Void>() {}));
p.run();
```

This is one of the common family of cases where Dataflow is used as an embarassingly-parallel orchestration framework rather than a data processing framework, but it should work.

You will need Dataflow SDK 1.2.0 to use the MapElements transform (support for Java 8 lambdas is new in 1.2.0).

Comment: I seem to need to specify a Coder. Is there one that will work for `GcsPath` or do I need to implement my own? Or should I convert to `String`s and make new `GcsPath`s in the processor?

Comment: Converting to String is probably easiest. Or you can use SerializableCoder.of().

Comment: Thanks. Full minimal example [here](https://gist.github.com/zbjornson/ac6a378129f1675ca5ff?ts=4).

Comment: Cool, looks reasonable!